# Android emulate home key launch intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-launcher, android-homebutton

In some Emulators, if the user presses the home key in the launcher, it does a different task than if you switch to it from another app:

For example, if the user presses home, it launches home. But if the user presses home again in the launcher, it opens the app drawer.

I am wondering how this can be done? I tried to emulate the home launch intent by setting intent action as `ACTION_MAIN` and category as `CATEGORY_HOME` to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that when an `Activity` is already in memory, then the new call to `startActivity()` will result in `Activity.onNewIntent()` being called, rather than the usual `onCreate()` method.

- 1 click goes to `onCreate()`
- 2 clicks go to `onNewIntent()`

So you can implement this behaviour by overriding the `onNewIntent()` method.

---

For the long answer, rather look at a full description of the problem at this link:

- [Android launcher press home in launcher to go to default screen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13203826/383414)

I can not say it better than this.