# Android launcher press home in launcher to go to default screen

Tags: android, android-intent, android-launcher, android-homebutton

In the default android launcher, pressing home while in another activity will start the launcher. Pressing home again while in the launcher will reset to the default home screen page. I don't understand how this can be done. Android sends the same intent whether the launcher is in the foreground or not. Home key also cannot be intercepted by user apps.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Android sends the same intent whether the launcher is in the foreground or not.

Correct.

> Home key also cannot be intercepted by user apps.

Correct.

> I don't understand how this can be done.

If a call to `startActivity()` will result in the `Intent` being delivered to an existing instance of the activity, a new instance is not created (by definition) and the existing instance is called with `onNewIntent()` instead of `onCreate()`.

In the case of a home screen, typically the activity that truly *is* the home screen will use `android:launchMode="singleTask"` or `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` in the manifest, such as:

```
    <activity
        android:name="Launcher"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme"
        android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnspecified|adjustPan">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

(from [an old launcher in the AOSP](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_launcher/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml))

Then, the activity can implement `onNewIntent()` to do something. In the case of the aforementioned old launcher, [its `onNewIntent()` includes](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_launcher/blob/master/src/com/android/launcher/Launcher.java):

```
            if (!mWorkspace.isDefaultScreenShowing()) {
                mWorkspace.moveToDefaultScreen();
            }
```

This, presumably, animates the UI back to the default screen if the user is presently viewing some other screen within the set of screens managed by the home screen activity.

Another approach to trigger `onNewIntent()`, instead of using `android:launchMode`, is to do it selectively when you call `startActivity()`, by including appropriate flags in the `Intent`, such as `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the information. I tried the another approach to trigger onNewIntent() by adding FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT with and without FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP but onNewIntent() is not triggered. Is there something Im missing? Thanks

Comment: @kevdliu: Hmmmm... try the combination of `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`, then. I know that works, as I use it in some of my NFC sample apps for getting the NFC tag event to the running activity (instead of starting up another copy). I thought `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` would have the same effect. Bear in mind that `onNewIntent()` will only be invoked if the activity already exists -- if you used `finish()` or the BACK button to get rid of the activity, it'll have to create a new one and call `onCreate()`, not `onNewIntent()`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I accepted your answer because it answered my original question. But I am actually trying to code a homescreen launcher app that simulates the launch behavior of the home key. If you can help me out I would really appreciate it. I got the launch intent for the home screen with getLaunchIntentForPackage(), added the flags, and startactivity(). However the onNewIntent() of the launcher is not called.

Comment: @kevdliu: You would have to look at the source code for your launcher, then, as I have no idea what it might be doing. And, if you do not have such source code, you are probably out of luck.

Comment: I think the deciding factor is 
if ((intent.getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT) !=
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT)

Answer (score 5):

to be more specific, do

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    if ((intent.getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT) !=
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT) {
        goHome();
    }
}
```